# Importing a map from the Google Maps API

Tags: import, internet, geography

I want to import the map [here](http://scimaps.org/mapdetail/map_of_complexity_sc_154).

I tried using `URLExecute`, as in the example [here](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/url-manipulation/call-urls-like-functions.html) and got nothing.

```
URLExecute["http://scimaps.org/maps/map/map_of_complexity_sc_154/\
detail", "Method" -> "GET"]
```

Comment: The URL points to a web app built with JavaScript and the Google maps API. Downloading it is like downloading Google Maps, it doesn't give you an image. (Possibly one could have a look at the source code and try to grab the map tiles from the server.)

Comment: @C.E. yeah, let me take the SVG part out of the question. It isn't really relevant. The import is failing even though I'm using an example from the Google maps API as guide.

Comment: The URL in the example that you linked to is to the static Google Maps API. Static means image. So you download an image, and you get an image. In your case you have a web app, if download a web app you get HTML. To turn the HTML into an image you need to render it, that's the job of a browser. There is no good *Mathematica* answer to this question.